# Insert Script on Google SpreadSheet programmatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I would like to know if it is possible to insert a [Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/) in a GDocs SpreadSheet using the [Google SpreadSheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/).
I want to insert my script in a list of SpreadSheets but don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Same issue here. @Guy : few purposes are : keep code in one single place, fixes and enhances all spreadsheets at once, debug one code not copied/pasted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to insert the same script into multiple spreadsheets, but I can suggest a reverse approach. If you have the script in a specific spreadsheet you can copy it again and again with Google Document List API:(http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CopyingDocs).

Since it is easy to put data into a spreadsheet, you can copy your data into the newly created copy of the spreadsheet with the given script.